# Ayuda con jcombobox en Netbeans?

Tags: java

Pasa que necesito que un combobox filtre los datos por sucursales. Si se la clic en un ítem me muestre en un jtable los datos de tal sucursal. Estoy usando un archivo de texto como base de datos (así me lo pidieron)  solo pude hacer que guarde y elimine... Sería de mucha ayuda q me pudieran colaborar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy usando un método para guardar los datos en un txt, guarda todo lo escrito en el jtable.

A lo mucho que pude llegar es por medio de este código...

```
Scanner entrada = null;

    String linea;

    int numeroDeLinea = 1;

    boolean contiene = false;

String texto = (String) jcomboSucursal.getSelectedItem();

    try {

        File f = new File("archivo. txt" );

        entrada = new Scanner(f);

        while (entrada.hasNext()) { //mientras no se llegue al final del fichero

               linea = entrada.nextLine();  

            if (linea.contains(texto)) {   //si la línea contiene el texto buscado se muestra por pantalla

                System.out.println("Linea " + numeroDeLinea + ": " + linea);

                contiene = true;

            }

            numeroDeLinea++; //se incrementa el contador de líneas

        }

        if(!contiene){ //si el archivo no contienen el texto se muestra un mensaje indicándolo

            System.out.println(texto + " no se ha encontrado en el archivo");

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString() + "No ha seleccionado ningún archivo");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());

    } finally {

        if (entrada != null) {

            entrada.close();

        }

    }
```

Aunque sólo me muestra por consola y yo quiero me filtre los datos y los muestre en mi jtable

Comment: Hola Cristian, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para que tu pregunta sea de calidad no solo has de explicar lo que quieres/necesitas si no tambien explicar lo que has investigado e intentado. Sobre eso, nosotros si podemos ayudarte más que en la tarea en si. Añade ejemplos de resultados actuales y resultados esperados y la informacion que falta siguiendo [ask] y [mcve] y pulsando en [edit] para añadirla. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Cristhian, podrias ayudarme con mi duda? Necesitas que ese Jtable cambie al cambiar el item de tu Combox? y si podrias mostrar el text que estas usando para cargar la tabla

Comment: este es mi metodo para mostrar en jtable try{

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("DatosTabla.txt");
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
 String input = bf.readLine();
 String[] temp;
 temp = input.split(",");
  while(input!=null)
  {
   temp = input.split(",");
   //for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                             modelo.addRow(temp);
    //System.out.println(temp[i]);
   //}
   input = bf.readLine();
  }
 }catch(Exception e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "error");
 }'

Comment: @Emilio hola, eso es exactamente lo que quiero, es decir que mi combobox tengan cargados las sucursales y al seleccionar una ,,,por ejemplo, seleccionar la sucursal "España" y que en el jtable me muestre todos los funcionarios de ahi mas sus correos pero solo de esa sucursal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Bueno en este caso puedes utilizar el evento Changue del Jcombobox.
Primero vamos a modificar nuestro método actual para que el mismo recorra busque el texto y la vez lo cargue en nuestra tabla.,Quedaría así nuestro método.
Recuerda declar tu DefaultTableModel para utilizarlo Aquí.

```
/*
Método que recibe como parámetro un String que seria nuestra sucursal en este caso.
*/
private void buscaText(String texto){
Scanner entrada = null;
String linea;
int numeroDeLinea = 1;
boolean contiene = false;
try {
    File f = new File("C:\\textop.txt");
    entrada = new Scanner(f);
    while (entrada.hasNext()) { //mientras no se llegue al final del fichero
           linea = entrada.nextLine();  
        if (linea.contains(texto)) {   //si la línea contiene el texto buscado se muestra por pantalla
            System.out.println("Se econtro en la Linea " + numeroDeLinea + ": " + linea);
             contiene=true;
            ///cargamos la tabla con un nuevo metodo
            ///recorremos la linea encontrada y cargamos fila a la tabla
            ///cada registro que se encuentre se cargara a la tabla.
            String[] temp; 
            temp = linea.split(","); 

            for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                modelo.addRow(temp);
              System.out.println(temp[i]); 
           }

        }

        numeroDeLinea++; //se incrementa el contador de líneas

    }

    if(!contiene){ //si el archivo no contienen el texto se muestra un mensaje indicándolo
        System.out.println(texto + " no se ha encontrado en el archivo");
    }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString() + "No ha seleccionado ningún archivo");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
} finally {
    if (entrada != null) {
        entrada.close();
    }    

}


}
```

En el evento del Combobox .

```
private void jComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                           
    String Nombre= jComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    ///obtenemos el nombre de la sucursal.
   ///ejecutamos nuestro nuevo método.
    buscaText(Nombre);
}
```

Espero haberte Ayudado.!